# Acl not working Getting error that ID is empty

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, acl

I have an Acl that i am trying to implement on my site which is database driven. I have used this code here [creating ACL with database](http://www.developerfiles.com/creating-acl-with-database-in-zend-framework/). I am using a module based structure and this example happens to not be. So i placed everything that is supposed to go in application model, in the core module model. This script authenticates everyone that views the site and if they do not have a account it logs them in as guest. My issue is that it authenticates the user as Guest but i am getting an error on the mapper getbyId, it has the user id as 1 (guest) why is it returning and error? Is it something with the module based structure i am using?

I tried posting on the site itself but have not gotten an answer yet, it was developed a while ago - blog might be dead.

thank you for your help!
Updated 6:44 EST May 2nd:

I think my problem lies here:

```
    private static function getAuthAdapter($loginField='login')
    {
        $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);
        $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
        ->setIdentityColumn($loginField)
        ->setCredentialColumn('password')
        ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(CONCAT(?,salt))');
        return $authAdapter;
    }
```

I already have an established data connection through my application.ini and Bootstrap.

```
    protected function _initDatabases()
    {
    $this->bootstrap('multidb');
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $databases = Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->multidb;
    foreach ($databases as $name => $adapter)
    {
        $db_adapter = $resource->getDb($name);
        Zend_Registry::set($name, $db_adapter);
    }
    }
```

So now the question would be - How do i change the getAuthAdapter to use what i already have?

thanks again

Updated 9:38 EST May 3rd:

The above now is not an issue. actually it never was. As i dug further, when i created the Guest User it did not encrypt the password and did not add salt. So now i am logged in but still have same error. 
This error comes from not getting the role_id.

```
if (!$auth->hasIdentity()){
   $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
   $role_id = $auth->getIdentity()->role_id;
   echo "Role Id =" . $role_id; exit;
   } else {
     echo "No Identity"; exit;
   }
```

The above returns - Role Id = 
So i have Identity why can i not get role_id - where role_id is the column name.

thanks again.

Updated 10:17 May 3:
For every ones knowledge. This is fixed. I have not explanation other than it was in some kinda of funk. I cleared the identity and it logged back on as Guest and the site came up.

So problem solved for me. This is a really great script so if you are looking for a data driven ACL dont hesitate to use the link above.

thanks